# Url Mappings in Grails: How to execute random code in UrlMappings closure

Tags: grails, url-rewriting, mapping

I want to execute code in UrlMappings. It can be done like that:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        group("/rest") {
            "/houses"(resources: 'house', namespace: 'rest'){
                "/doors"(resources:'door', namespace:'rest') {
                    foo = { 
                        params.context = [ house: [ id: params.houseId ] ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could be a solution but I would prefer not to add that additional "foo" variable. Changing foo by houseId is a better solution but still not elegant. Is there any other possibility to execute arbitrary code in the mapping definition?

Comment: You can put any valid Groovy code you like in there.  It isn't clear why you might want to do that, but you can.

Comment: Can you describe what kinds of things you want this code to do, and when it is that you want that code to be executed?  I can't tell if you want to evaluate code while the mappings are being defined, or when they are selected when a request comes in, or some other time.

Comment: I want to add a Map variable to params. If I add it directly, it is converted to String: "/doors"(resources:'door', namespace:'rest') { context = [ house: [ id: params.houseId ] ] }

Comment: I deleted my answer because your questions below make it clear to me that I don't understand the question.  I am sorry for the trouble.  All the best.

Comment: If you want to add variable to params maybe it's better to use grails filters?